# Laravel 'syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)' within Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following code to decide which modal shall open by pressing this button.

```
<button type="button" style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{ Auth::check () ? '#loginmodal' : '#passengermodal'}}{{$trip->id}}">JETZT BUCHEN</button>
```

The Website crashes with the message

```
'syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)'
```

I don't know why it's crashing.

Comment: I think it's different code which is giving your error.

Comment: tell the line number and post all code of that file